# PHP imagejpeg() Not Working On Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

I am working on image cropping functionality for my website. I sent my PHP script an array of the cropped image dimensions (x , y, width, height);

The script successfully crops the image on my localhost but does not work when pushed to my web server.

```
<?php
    $array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $targ_w = 542;
    $targ_h = 671;

    $src = $array[0];
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$array[1],$array[2],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$array[3],$array[4]);

    $time = time();

    if (imagejpeg($dst_r, 'temp_crops/temp_'.$time.'.jpg'))
        echo "made it";
    else
        echo "didnt make it :(";

    //echo $time;
?>
```

AJAX Post:

```
$('#crop_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            var array = [$('#profile_preview').attr('src'), $('#x').val(), $('#y').val(), $('#w').val(), $('#h').val()];
            if (checkCoords()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : '../../application/views/poster/crop.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data : JSON.stringify(array),
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        $('#profile_preview').attr('src', '../../application/views/poster/temp_crops/temp_'+data+".jpg");
                        $('#final_img_src').val('temp_'+data+'.jpg');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Local host response is: `made it`.
Web server response is: `didnt make it :(`.

Can anybody help me out and tell me why this isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: Does the server have GD installed? Double check the error logs on the server to see if there is some error happening.

Comment: I'm not sure where the error logs are. I checked `var/log/apache2` but I do not have an apache2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check for GD library - within script with if(!function_exists('imagejpeg')) ... 
Otherwise error logs maybe in /var/log/httpd/

Comment: debian/ubuntu systems logs are in `/var/log/apache2`

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that your PHP script does not have permission to write to that location on the server. Use your FTP software to CHMOD (change permissions) to allow write to the directory you are trying to store these in. That should do it unless your webhost has disabled PHP from writing files locally at all (in which case, you should talk to them and see what options are available).